# Getting icons from odsp-next on-prem via SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2019

We have a custom build SPFx webpart that takes icons via this path:
/_layouts/15/next/odspnext/odsp-media/images/itemtypes/20/
We upgraded SharePoint 2019 to SSE and the icons in the webpart stopped working, giving 404 error "not found".
Fine enough, we went and manually added these icons/resources to the correct path (folder 16, as this will resolve to 15), copying from the old server to the new one. We tried again and we still get 404 error even though the files exist on the correct path now. How come?

We dont believe anyone manually added the icons etc. on this path and we couldnt find anything on our code base that could provision these out. Where could these resources come from? We should not be adding files manually in the hive and could potentially be the reason why our manual intervention didnt work.